# Embeding a Word Office Document in

Tags: html, ms-word, docx

I am trying to embed a Word document into my HTML code, but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried to use an iframe tag in order to place show it with fixed height and width, but all it does is opening the document, instead of showing it within the requested borders.

```
<iframe src="test.docx" width="100%" height="500">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Which browser and version? I guess it's not impossible that you could embed Word documents in IE out of the box, but it sounds unlikely.

Comment: @Juhana any browser, even Chrome won't let me do it.

Comment: That's what I meant. You can't display Word documents in a browser as-is. Browsers just don't have that feature. It might be possible in IE, but it's certainly not possible in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

.docx and other Microsoft Office file formats are patented and cannot be used or accessed directly as Microsoft hasn't given the permissions to Google or any other browsers.

You can convert it to .pdf.

Or you can use [Zoho writer](http://writer.zoho.com/).

Check it out : [Link](http://labnol.blogspot.in/2007/03/how-to-embed-microsoft-office-or-pdf.html)